# Generate table, store values from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create tables for each index in a given array, also i need to store those values so that my for loops sends them to the tables created.

JavaScript: 
`for (c=0; c < components_count.length; c++)
{
    console.log(components_count[c]);
}`

how can this be done?

Here is the full JS:

```
var index;
var data;
var parsed;

    $(document).ready(function() {
     $.get('policy.json', function(data){
  index = data;

 },"json");

 });

function search(){

var movement_select = $("#movements").val();

var id = $("#idSubmit").val();

var refnr = index.refnr;

var index_movements = index.movements;

//console.log(movement_select);

//for loop to test which movement from dropdown list! Done!

for (m=0; m < index_movements.length; m++)
{

    if (index_movements[m].date == movement_select)
    {
        movement_select = index_movements[m];

    }

}


var movements = index.movements;
var movements_description = movement_select.description;    
var movements_premium = movement_select.premium;

var movements_payer = movement_select.payer;
var movements_payer_id = movement_select.payer.personid;
var movements_payer_name = movement_select.payer.name;
var movements_payer_surname = movement_select.payer.surname;
var movements_payer_fullname = movements_payer_name + " " + movements_payer_surname;

var movements_owner = movement_select.owner;
var movements_owner_id = movement_select.owner.personid;
var movements_owner_name = movement_select.owner.name;
var movements_owner_surname = movement_select.owner.surname;
var movements_owner_fullname = movements_owner_name + " " + movements_owner_surname;

var components_count = movement_select.components;

for (c=0; c < components_count.length; c++)
{
    console.log(components_count[c]);
}

var components = movement_select.components[0];
var components_description = movement_select.components[0].description;
var components_premium = movement_select.components[0].premium;
var components_cover = movement_select.components[0].cover;
var components_commencementdate = movement_select.components[0].commencementdate;

// table 1 --------------------------------------------------

$("#id").html(id);
$("#refnr").html(refnr);
$("#movements_payer_fullname").html(movements_payer_fullname);
$("#movements_owner_fullname").html(movements_owner_fullname);
$("#refnr").html(refnr);

// table 2 --------------------------------------------------


}
```

and here is the JSON:

```
{
"policyid":"1000",
"refnr":"gcsa000923",
"movements":
[
    {
        "date":"2012/06/01",
        "description":"Accept",
        "premium":"R30.00",
        "payer":{"personid":"928374","name":"Hansie","surname":"slim"},
        "owner":{"personid":"928374","name":"Hansie","surname":"slim"},
        "components":
        [
            {
                "description":"Basic cover",
                "premium":"R10.00",
                "cover":"R0.00",
                "commencementdate":"2012/06/01"
            },
            {
                "description":"Cancer",
                "premium":"R10.00",
                "cover":"R20 000.00",
                "commencementdate":"2012/06/01"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date":"2012/08/01",
        "description":"Policy Alteration",
        "premium":"R30.00",
        "payer":{"personid":"928374","name":"Hansie","surname":"slim"},
        "owner":{"personid":"928374","name":"Hansie","surname":"slim"},
        "components":
        [
            {
                "description":"Basic cover",
                "premium":"R10.00",
                "cover":"R0.00",
                "commencementdate":"2012/06/01"
            },
            {
                "description":"Cancer",
                "premium":"R10.00",
                "cover":"R20 000.00",
                "commencementdate":"2012/06/01"
            },
            {
                "description":"Disability cover",
                "premium":"R20.00",
                "cover":"R40 000.00",
                "commencementdate":"2012/09/01"
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

}

Solved: 
`for (c=0; c < components_count.length; c++)
    {
        $('#append').append("Description: " + components_count[c].description + " " + '<br>');
        $('#append').append("Premium: " + components_count[c].premium + " " + '<br>');
        $('#append').append("Cover: " + components_count[c].cover + " " + '<br>');
        $('#append').append("Commencement Date: " + components_count[c].commencementdate + " " + '<br>' + '<br>');
    }`

I forgot about .append ^^

Comment: Could you please be more specific and post more code? Note that JSON is just a JavaScript object once you JSON.parse it

Comment: @Snake Eater, what is the problem here?